# Alternatives to ANOVA for kill assay

Tags: r, bioinformatics, anova

I'm trying to find an appropriate test to compare my data.
I ran an ANOVA to compare different drug concentrations' effects on bacterial population count at different time points. I believe that the lack of internal variance in my data is causing massive differences in means to be statistically non-significant. At one given time point I have 0 bacteria in one treatment group and 1*10^11 bacteria in the untreated group and this difference is not considered statistically significant. is there any alternative statistical tests which I could use to compare my data at an individual time point or alternatively compare the trend over time as a whole?

Comment: You need to give some more information, maybe you can show us some plots, and details of the analysis?

Comment: Please don't cross-post or repost your question.